# How to fix "TypeError: a float is required" message?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Python and I get this error:

> TypeError: a float is required.

Here is my code:

```
cv2.putText(img,str(sampleNum + 1), (x,y+h+30),font, (255,255,255))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace**

```
cv2.putText(img,str(sampleNum + 1), (x,y+h+30),font, (255,255,255))
```

**with**

```
cv2.putText(img, str(sampleNum + 1), (x,y+h+30), font, 2, 255)
```

More Info on **[putText](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext)** method

Answer (score 1):

The fifth argument is font scale, which must be a `double`.  You have a 3-tuple there.

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext

Comment: can you help me to solving my code?

`if (profile != None) :
                    if (conf > 80):
                        cv2.putText(im,"Siapa Anda?", (x,y+h+30),font, (255,255,255))
                    else:
                        cv2.putText(im,str(profile[0]), (x,y+h+30),font, (255,255,255))
                        cv2.putText(im,str(profile[1]), (x,y+h+60),font, (255,255,255))
                        cv2.putText(im,str(conf), (x,y+h+80),font, (255,0,0))
            else :
                cv2.putText(im,"Anda siapa ?", (x,y+h+60),font, (255,255,255))`
i'm using opencv-contrib 3+